# How can I add "dots" between the nodes of my neural network diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, draw

I want to represent my ANN for a article, but with 12 neurons it become way too polluted. So how can I add the three dots after a node and than add the last node to it?
[image]

```
               \documentclass{standalone}
                    \usepackage{tikz}
                    \begin{document}
                    \pagestyle{empty}
                    \def\layersep{3cm}
                    \def\nodeinlayersep{1.5cm}
                    \begin{tikzpicture}[
                       shorten >=1pt,->,
                       draw=black!50,
                        node distance=\layersep,
                        every pin edge/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt},
                        neuron/.style={circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt},
                        input neuron/.style={neuron, fill=green!50},
                        output neuron/.style={neuron, fill=red!50},
                        hidden neuron/.style={neuron, fill=blue!50},
                        annot/.style={text width=4em, text centered}
                    ]
                        % Draw the input layer nodes
                        \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
                        % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
                            \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \#\y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {};
                        % set number of hidden layers
                        \newcommand\Nhidden{2}
                        % Draw the hidden layer nodes
                        \foreach \N in {1,...,\Nhidden} {
                           \foreach \y in {1,...,12} {
                              \path[yshift=7cm]
                              node[hidden neuron] (H\N-\y) at (\N*\layersep,-\y*\nodeinlayersep ) {$\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$};
                               }
                        \node[annot,above of=H\N-1, node distance=1cm] (hl\N) {Hidden layer \N};
                        }
                        % Draw the output layer node
                        \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H\Nhidden-6] (O) {};
        %
                        % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
                        % hidden layer.
                        \foreach \source in {1,...,3}
                            \foreach \dest in {1,...,12}
                                \path (I-\source) edge (H1-\dest);
                        % connect all hidden stuff
                        \foreach [remember=\N as \lastN (initially 1)] \N in {2,...,\Nhidden}
                           \foreach \source in {1,...,12}
                               \foreach \dest in {1,...,12}
                                   \path (H\lastN-\source) edge (H\N-\dest);
                        % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
                        \foreach \source in {1,...,12}
                            \path (H\Nhidden-\source) edge (O);
                        % Annotate the layers
                        \node[annot,left of=hl1] {Input layer};
                        \node[annot,right of=hl\Nhidden] {Output layer};
                    \end{tikzpicture}
                    % End of code
                    \end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, do you want three dots between each layer? Or three dots from each node in layer n to each node in layer n+1?

Comment: I want to add dots after the 4th node of each hidden layer.

Comment: Can you draw it in paint?

Comment: I'm not at all sure what you want so my answer has some options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you were after? I've added comments in the code where I've changed things.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\def\layersep{3cm}
\def\nodeinlayersep{1.5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   shorten >=1pt,->,
   draw=black!50,
    node distance=\layersep,
    every pin edge/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt},
    neuron/.style={circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt},
    input neuron/.style={neuron, fill=green!50},
    output neuron/.style={neuron, fill=red!50},
    hidden neuron/.style={neuron, fill=blue!50},
    annot/.style={text width=4em, text centered}
]
    % Draw the input layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
    % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
    \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \#\y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y-2.5) {};  %%% <-- MODIFIED
    % set number of hidden layers
    \newcommand\Nhidden{2}

    % Draw the hidden layer nodes
    \foreach \N in {1,...,\Nhidden} {
       \foreach \y in {1,...,5} { %%% MODIFIED (1,...,12 -> 1,...,5, and the next five lines)
         \ifnum \y=4
           \node at (\N*\layersep,-\y*\nodeinlayersep) {$\vdots$};
         \else
           \node[hidden neuron] (H\N-\y) at (\N*\layersep,-\y*\nodeinlayersep ) {$\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$};
         \fi
       }
    \node[annot,above of=H\N-1, node distance=1cm] (hl\N) {Hidden layer \N};
    }
    % Draw the output layer node
    \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H\Nhidden-3] (O) {}; %%% <-- MODIFIED (from H\Nhidden-6 to H\Nhidden-3) 
    % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
    % hidden layer.
    \foreach \source in {1,...,3}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,3,5} %%% <-- MODIFIED (1,...,12 -> 1...,3,5)
            \path (I-\source) edge (H1-\dest);
    % connect all hidden stuff
    \foreach [remember=\N as \lastN (initially 1)] \N in {2,...,\Nhidden}
       \foreach \source in {1,...,3,5} %%% <-- MODIFIED (1,...,12 -> 1...,3,5)
           \foreach \dest in {1,...,3,5} %%% <-- MODIFIED (1,...,12 -> 1...,3,5)
               \path (H\lastN-\source) edge (H\N-\dest);
    % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
    \foreach \source in {1,...,3,5} %%% <-- MODIFIED (1,...,12 -> 1...,3,5)
        \path (H\Nhidden-\source) edge (O);
    % Annotate the layers
    \node[annot,left of=hl1] {Input layer};
    \node[annot,right of=hl\Nhidden] {Output layer};
\end{tikzpicture}
% End of code
\end{document}
```

Comment: As I will have to make another alterations, I'd like to know how I can change the space between the nodes vertically. @TorbjørnT.

Comment: @CaioCustódio Change `\nodeinlayersep`?